# SQL Query producing results in reverse order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the columns `TIMESTAMP` and `REMAINING`. I am trying to order the `TIMESTAMP` in descending order, but have the `REMAINING` column output the results in a very specific order which is:

1. AgentStateEvent
2. TerminalConnectionCreated
3. Whatever else

However it is resulting like this (reverse order from what I can tell):

```
TIMESTAMP|| REMAINING
%[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=CallControlTerminalConnectionHeld]
%[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated][callID=11411]
%[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=agentStateEvent]
%[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=CallControlTerminalConnectionHeld]
%[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated][callID=11411]
%[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=CallControlTerminalConnectionHeld]
%[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated]
%[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=agentStateEvent]
%[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=agentStateEvent]
```

when it should be:

```
   %[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=agentStateEvent]
 %[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated][callID=11411]
 %[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=CallControlTerminalConnectionHeld]
```

etc...

The SQL I currently have is as follows:

```
select *
from [TIMESTAMP_ORGANISER].[dbo].[TEST_DB]
order by 
    timestamp,
    case 
       when remaining like '%[EVENT=agentStateEvent]%' then 1
       when remaining like '%[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated]%' then 2 
       else 3
    end;
```

I have tried to do an inverse of the SQL like so:

```
select *
from [TIMESTAMP_ORGANISER].[dbo].[TEST_DB]
order by 
    timestamp,
    case 
       when remaining like '%[EVENT=agentStateEvent]%' then 3
       when remaining like '%[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated]%' then 2 
       else 1
    end;
```

but that makes no difference. What I am doing wrong?

EDIT, have tried the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TIMESTAMP_ORGANISER].[dbo].[TEST_DB]
ORDER BY 
    timestamp, 
    CASE 
       WHEN remaining LIKE '%agentStateEvent%' THEN -3
       WHEN remaining LIKE '%TerminalConnectionCreated%' THEN -2
       ELSE -1 
    END
```

unfortunately results ends up like this:

```
 %[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=agentStateEvent]
 %[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=agentStateEvent]
 %[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=agentStateEvent]
 %[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=agentStateEvent]
 %[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=agentStateEvent]
%[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated]%
[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated]%
[TIMESTAMP=1441737006102]||[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply all your `CASE` rankings by -1 to get the order you want:

```
SELECT * FROM [TIMESTAMP_ORGANISER].[dbo].[TEST_DB]
ORDER BY timestamp, CASE WHEN remaining LIKE '%agentStateEvent%' THEN -1
                         WHEN remaining LIKE '%TerminalConnectionCreated%' THEN -2
                    ELSE -3 END
```

I also changed your `LIKE` matching conditions because from your results it appears that even things were out of order in the original query which you don't want.

Comment: Already stated this in my comments that I have tried that but it still produces the exact same result :(

Comment: Tried the new answer, unfortunately this changes the output altogether (see original post with results)

Comment: The new output looks exactly like what you are asking for.  Then what is the problem?

Comment: Why not add `case when remaining like '%[EVENT=agentStateEvent]%' then 3 
when remaining like '%[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated]%'  then 2 
else 1  end` to the `Select` query to make sure you are getting the correct results returned?

Comment: @MiguelH Good idea, but I'm surprised that the answer I gave didn't fix his problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Order by remaining desc, case when remaining like '%[EVENT=agentStateEvent]%' then 1
          when remaining like '%[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated]%' then 2 
          else 3
     end asc;
```

Comment: If didn't work, put the case when in the select list and make sure the rank was returned correctly. May be it is case sensitive